# vaadin flow springboot redirect to custom route after successful login

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, vaadin-flow

I have a simple application written in vaadin flow and springboot. I have spring security dependency as well.

My login view looks like this

```
@Route("login")
@AnonymousAllowed
public class LoginView extends VerticalLayout {

    public LoginView() {

        var login = new LoginForm();
        login.setAction("login");

        add(
                new H1("Something"),
                login
        );
    }
}
```

My security configuration looks like this

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends VaadinWebSecurity {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);
        setLoginView(http, LoginView.class);
    }

    @Bean
    UserDetailsManager userDetailsManager(){
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(
                User.withUsername("xxx")
                        .password("{noop}xxx")
                        .roles("USER").build()
        );
    }
}
```

when I start the application, I am trying to reach this from the browser, which is getting redirected to /login. All good so far. When I enter my preconfigured username and password, I am able to login, but by default it is redirecting me to the path `/`.
How can I make it to redirect to another route for example "/dashboard" where I have another view setup

```
@Route("dashboard")
@PermitAll
public class MemberView extends VerticalLayout {
   .....
}
```